# Assembly - get a character from the keyboard without printing it

Tags: assembly, dosbox

As a project for my school, I am programming a "connect 4" game in assembly.
 I am trying to get a character from the keyboard using

```
mov ah, 1
int 21h
```

However, now when I click "1" in the keyboard, the program works and does what it needs to do, but, it is also printing an annoying "1" in the top left of the screen. For example, this is what happened when I clicked "1" five times:
[image]

How do I get a character from the keyboard without printing it?

Comment: Use `int 21h / ah=08h` if you want the same behavior as `int 21h / ah=01h` but without the echo.

Comment: @Michael Thanks! I noticed that ah=07h works too. What is the difference between 07 and 08?

Comment: See e.g. http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html